# Annotate an image twice

Tags: php, imagick

I annotate an image using Imagick:

```
$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('#ffffff');
$draw->setFont('fonts/opensans-regular.ttf');
$draw->setFontSize(40);
$image->annotateImage($draw, 20, 100, 0, 'The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog');

$image->setImageFormat('png');

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

How can i Use annotateImage() twice in order to insert to text elements with different positions? When I just copy the draw paragraph, the last use isn't visible. Do I have to save the image and edit it again or exists a way to do it on the fly? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Just adding a second ImagickDraw() doesn't work, it is not visible.

```
$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');

//first
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('#ffffff');
$draw->setFont('fonts/opensans-regular.ttf');
$draw->setFontSize(40);
$image->annotateImage($draw, 20, 100, 0, 'The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog');

//second
$draw2 = new ImagickDraw();
$draw2->setFillColor('red');
$draw2->setFont('fonts/opensans-regular.ttf');
$draw2->setFontSize(40);
$image->annotateImage($draw2, 20, 800, 0, 'The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog');

$image->setImageFormat('png');

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

Comment: Include the code you've tried that isn't working for you. Likely someone can tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Never done it, but it seems to me if you do a second `annotateImage` with different `X` and `Y` co-ordinates it should do what you are asking

Comment: How did you try to use it twice? Shouldn't it just work by adding: `$draw2 = new ImagickDraw();` and do the same with that as with the first?

Comment: I've added my try in an update.

Comment: No just do 2 annotateImage's one after the other WITH DIFFERENT X and Y Co-ordinates. @srayhunter understood what i ment as was so impressed he made my comment into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a 2nd annotation that you can add to the image.

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'white' );
$image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);

$draw->setFillColor('black');
$draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );

$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 25, 0, '1st line of annotation text here');
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 60, 0, '2nd line of annotation text here');
$image->setImageFormat('png');

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

Based on the `x,y` coordinates you can add annotations where you like. Just remember that they can overlap and over each other.

Comment: Yes that is what I ment in my comment